# Table Borders won't print when added to display

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, printing

I've encountered this problem every so often over the last few years. When adding tables to the display in ArcMap, the following occurs when printing the map:

1. All table borders visible on the display but do not print
2. All Table borders visible on the display, but only top and left border prints
3. Only top and left table borders visible, yet all borders print
4. All table borders visible and all print (as it should be)

What frustrates me about this is that it is extremely inconsistent - I can have 4 tables on my display and 2 will print perfectly while the other 2 won't. I can move the tables slightly, then the original 2 won't print right while the other 2 will. Today I can print it perfectly, tomorrow I can open that same mxd and print without making any changes, and the tables will print wrong.

As a workaround I've always had to draw a rectangle around the table, align the borders and group each table with its border (and if its more than 3 tables, this quickly becomes annoying). This problem has "haunted" me since version 9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you selecting borders explicitly from table properties in the layout?

I just added a table to layout, and the default print preview did not show any borders at all, but after I selected a 1-point border, it showed pretty good on the print (using CutePDF).

Refer [this article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/19/using-tables-in-an-arcmap-layout/) from ESRI for more details.

Btw, I am using ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: No, I was referring to the default table edges which are added once you add it to the layout. It did not occur to me to right click the table since it is now a graphic (argh...). Thanks for the excellent link as well, I've tested a few prints from different mxds and the tables are printing consistently each time.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)